# Vue.js short and clean syntax for data

Tags: vue.js

I started using **vue.js** and i would like to know if there is any best way **(clean)** to declare my **data variables**:
for example i have :

```
profileInfos: {
   name:null,
   email: null,
   mobile: null
},
```

when i do :

```
profileInfos: {name, email, mobile},
```

i get an error message : email not defined

can i declare profileInfos without the keys `name, email, mobile`  and use `v-text` in my html tags ?

Comment: Sure you can. you can initialize it as an empty property. `profileInfos: {}` and when you want to write to that object and create these keys, you can use `this.$set(this.profileInfos, 'email', value)`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do:

declare

```
profileInfos: {}
```

then you can straightforwardly set undeclared property up to 1 level of the object like:

```
this.profileInfos.name = 'my Name'
```